# Managing data in two relational databases in a single location

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, bigdata

**Background:** We currently have our data split between two relational databases (Oracle and Postgres). There is a need to run ad-hoc queries that involve tables in both databases. Currently we are doing this in one of two ways:

1. ETL from one database to another. This requires a lot of developer 
   time.
2. [Oracle foreign data wrapper](https://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) on our
   Postgres server. This is working, but the queries run extremely
   slowly.

We already use Google Cloud Platform (for the project that uses the Postgres server). We are familiar with Google BigQuery (BQ).

**What we want to do:** 
We want most of our tables from both these databases (as-is) available at a single location, so querying them is easy and fast. We are thinking of copying over the data from both DB servers into BQ, without doing any transformations.

It looks like we need to take full dumps of our tables on a periodic basis (daily) and update BQ since BQ is [append-only](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#modifying-or-deleting-rows-or-data). The recent availability of [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) in BQ seems to be very limited.

We are aware that loading the tables as is to BQ is not an optimal solution and we need to denormalize for efficiency, but this is a problem we have to solve after analyzing the feasibility.

My question is whether BQ is a good solution for us, and if yes, how to efficiently keep BQ in sync with our DB data, or whether we should look at something else (like say, Redshift)?

Comment: I suggest that you do not complicate it with another data platform and instead just pick Oracle or postgres and replicate into there. Is replication into BQ any less developer intensive or cheaper than replicating into either Oracle or Postgres?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yep, on BQ a terabyte costs you $10 for long term. You cannot find for $10 machines that power Oracle or Postgres systems. BigQuery is the data lake and it's exactly for such a system.

Comment: The expense point is valid but the developer costs won't be cheaper than point 1: you would have to get the data from both places to the new place, not just one to the other. And presumably they have paid for those platforms already. They also want querying to be easy and fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WePay has been publishing a series of articles on how they solve these problems. Check out https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/streaming-databases-in-realtime-with-mysql-debezium-kafka.

To keep everything synchronized they:

> The flow of data starts with each microservice’s MySQL database. These
>   databases run in Google Cloud as CloudSQL MySQL instances with GTIDs
>   enabled. We’ve set up a downstream MySQL cluster specifically for
>   Debezium. Each CloudSQL instance replicates its data into the Debezium
>   cluster, which consists of two MySQL machines: a primary (active)
>   server and secondary (passive) server. This single Debezium cluster is
>   an operational trick to make it easier for us to operate Debezium.
>   Rather than having Debezium connect to dozens of microservice
>   databases directly, we can connect to just a single database. This
>   also isolates Debezium from impacting the production OLTP workload
>   that the master CloudSQL instances are handling.

And then:

> The Debezium connectors feed the MySQL messages into Kafka (and add
>   their schemas to the Confluent schema registry), where downstream
>   systems can consume them. We use our Kafka connect BigQuery connector
>   to load the MySQL data into BigQuery using BigQuery’s streaming API.
>   **This gives us a data warehouse in BigQuery that is usually less than
>   30 seconds behind the data that’s in production**. Other microservices,
>   stream processors, and data infrastructure consume the feeds as well.